# Loading issue when using amazon sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am trying to integrate amazon s3 in my project. The Gemfile is as follows.

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
```

development.rb

```
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :bucket => 'name_ofbucket'
    }
    Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

config/aws.yml

```
development:
  access_key_id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID

production:
  access_key_id: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID
```

Model

```
 has_attached_file :logo, styles: { medium: '300x300>', thumb: '150x150>' },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
                    :path => ":class/:attachment/:token/:style.:extension",
                    :bucket => 'name_of_bucket',
                    default_url: '/images/missing.jpg'
```

Now i am getting the following error.

> cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)

I have already installed the gems and restarted the server. 
I went through similar threads but could not resolve the issue.

I am not sure why i am receiving this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your Gemfile declares:

```
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
```

Whereas the error message says:

> cannot load such file -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)

Have you tried to put `gem 'aws-sdk'` in your Gemfile?

I know you just want to use `s3` and not the whole `aws-sdk`, but maybe `paperclip` requires a few more library to be loaded than the bar minimum.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because of I added the amazon s3_region wrong
If you are using S3 storage, aws-sdk >= 2.0.0 requires you to make a few small
changes:

- You must set the `s3_region`
- If you are explicitly setting permissions anywhere, such as in an initializer,
  note that the format of the permissions changed from using an underscore to
  using a hyphen. For example, `:public_read` needs to be changed to
  `public-read`.